# Como salvar arquvio sem sobrescrever o anterior python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ola, estou tentando salvar o nome dos arquivos de video de forma diferente toda vez que for executado o programa.
atualmente ele sobrescreve o nome do video anterior.

Este é o meu codigo atual:

```
import cv2
print("MODO DE VIDEO COM 2 CAMERAS")

#NUMERO DE CAMERAS
webcam1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
webcam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

#VERIFICANDO AS CAMERAS
if (webcam1.isOpened() == False):
    print("Camera 1 não conectada!")
if (webcam2.isOpened() == False):
    print("Camera 2 não conectada!")   

#ARMAZENAMENTO
nome1=("Video_camera1.avi")
nome2=("Video_camera1.avi")
fourcc1 = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"DIVX")
fourcc2 = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
file1 = cv2.VideoWriter(nome1,fourcc1, 10.0,(640,480))
file2 = cv2.VideoWriter(nome2,fourcc2, 10.0,(640,480))

while (True):
    ret, frame1 = webcam1.read()
    ret, frame2 = webcam2.read()

    if ret==True:
        file1.write(frame1)
        file2.write(frame2)

        cv2.imshow('Webcam1 1',frame1)
        cv2.imshow('Webcam1 2',frame2)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('s'):

            break
    else:
        break
print("FINALIZADO")
webcam1.release()
webcam2.release()
file1.release()
file2.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Basta alterar os valores de `nome1` e `nome2` que, aparentemente, serão os nomes dos arquivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o @Anderson Carlos Woss comentou acima você só precisa alterar `nome1` e `nome2`, mas se não quiser sempre abrir o código e alterar toda vez que for rodar ou se quiser deixar para o usuário escolher, considere fazer algo assim:

```
n1 = input("Digite o nome do primeiro arquivo: ")
n2 = input("Digite o nome do segundo arquivo: ")

nome1=(f"{n1}.avi")
nome2=(f"{n2}.avi")
```

E considere incluir algo para alterar o nome se já existir um arquivo com o texto digitado:

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile(f"seu_diretorio/{nome1}"): #seu_diretorio é o diretório onde 
#você vai gravar os arquivos
    n1 = input(f"Um arquivo com o nome {nome1} já existe. Por favor, digite outro nome: ")
    nome1=(f"{n1}.avi")
if os.path.isfile(f"seu_diretorio/{nome2}"):
    n2 = input(f"Um arquivo com o nome {nome2} já existe. Por favor, digite outro nome: ")
    nome2=(f"{n2}.avi")
```

Se você quiser salvar sem perguntar ao usuário, considere fazer algo assim:

```
import os           
import glob
n = int([os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob("seu_diretorio/*.txt")][-1][8:9])
n1 = n + 1
n2 = n1 + 1

nome1=(f"camera1_{n1}.avi")
nome2=(f"camera2_{n2}.avi")
```

Obs.: Neste último exemplo considerei os arquivos com nome seguindo o seguinte padrão: camera1_0.avi, camera1_1.avi, camera1_2.avi..

Comment: Gostaria de salvar sem perguntar ao usuário. Apenas incrementando algum número no final.  Tipo camera1_001, câmera1_002, camera1_00 etc

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando o mesmo nome para os arquivos nas variáveis `nome1` e `nome2`, por isso está sobrescrevendo.

Tenta mudar, dessa forma:

```
#ARMAZENAMENTO
nome1=("Video_camera1.avi")
nome2=("Video_camera2.avi")
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ficar de uma forma mais dinâmica e organizada, você pode colocar a data e hora no nome do arquivos, por exemplo

```
from datetime import datetime

data = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
nome1 = "video_camera1_{}.avi".format(data)
nome2 = "video_camera2_{}.avi".format(data)
```

O resultado será video_camera1_2019-07-01_14-38-12.avi e video_camera2_2019-07-01_14-38-12.avi

assim os nomes dos vídeos ficarão sempre diferentes, e não vão mais sobrescrever os antigos, e fica organizado, você sabe que arquivos é de que data e hora.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado